# Does PostgreSQL install a database somewhere?

Tags: database, postgresql

**I know this might sounds like a stupid question but I want to get this cleared up a bit:**

I was reading the docs for the `PostgreSQL RDBMS` and I was a little confused from this portion:

`A server process, which manages the database files, accepts connections to the database from client applications, and performs database actions on behalf of the clients. The database server program is called postgres.`

Is it required for us to create a `server program` to perform the usual `CRUD` operations?

Like from my knowledge I understand that you would have to write your own `API` (server) using `Node` or some other language that would be used to interact with the database (Mongo for example) on a separate server like Heroku or something.

But when installing `PostgreSQL` I noticed that you just install the `server Postgres` using this:

`/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1`

So do we not have to create an external API to manage the database files and accept connections from the clients by ourselves?

Comment: You don't need to write an API, you use SQL to query and modify the data that the server manages.

Comment: You should probably first learn what  "server", "service", API, and so on actually mean.  You're not using those terms correctly in your question -- so any correct answer is likely to be meaningless for you.

Comment: @user3137702 Can you please explain what is wrong in my terminology?

Comment: The database server itself manages the "database files" and "accepts connections" and this is true of *every* database with a server: Postgresql, Mysql, MSSQL, Oracle, Mongo, and so on.  You do not need to "create an external API" for any of them.  However, every time you used the term API in your question, you used it incorrectly, indicating you do not know what it means, and probably meant something else.

Comment: @user3137702 Oh ok I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database server process is the only way to get at the data in the database.  It does all the database things that need doing:  writing data to disk, reading data from disk, handling sql queries from clients, sending results to clients, managing transactions and locking.

Clients (typically written with an official PostgreSQL client library like libpq or libpq++) connect to the server and send requests and receive results.  The only way to really use the server is through some kind of client.  Clients can be categorized as administrative tools or apps.

Administrative tools:  "psql" is the basic command-line text client for interacting with the PostgreSQL server, the first and best client imho.  GUI tools like pgAdmin are also clients.  phpPgAdmin is a web app that uses PHP's PostgreSQL bindings (built on libpq) in its backend to talk to a server.

Apps are another important type of client.  You write your program in a language that has a client library available, and communicate with the server via the client library.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like SSMS for SQL Server? Yes, but there's a whole community page devoted to possible tools:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: Oh interesting I wasn't aware of this. I am just having a hard time understanding the difference between creating an application using `PostgreSQL` and creating an application using the `MEAN` stack for example. Like in the latter you have to build everything from ground up: CRUD operations, your own API, email/password reset. Is that all included in the `PostgreSQL RDBMS`? Since it is a management system that's what I originally thought of it.

Comment: Postgres is a DBMS. It manages *data* (using SQL) You can build anything on top of it that needs to store and retrieve data.

Comment: The "M" in "MEAN" stands for MongoDB, a NoSQL DBMS, so you could use Postgres instead of Mongo (PEAN?). Basically, Postgres runs as a service on the machine, just like SQL Server or Mongo do, and you need to write software that connects to that service. Once you have a connection, you can send it CRUD SQL commands. Postgres will manage the data by storing it on disk, evaluating the best way to run your query, store the indexes you create, etc. It can do almost everything SQL can do, it just lacks a GUI like SSMS. Another example is MS Access which has the database and GUI all rolled together.